# How to convert informal string value to Date time in c#

Tags: c#

All of my friend.
I want to convert informal string to dateTime in c#. Here my string value is `"01042016"`.How can convert? can i need another step to change `DateTime`.

This is my code:

```
string FinancialYear = "01042016-31032017";
string[] splitDate = FinancialYear.Split('-');
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(splitDate[0].ToString(),"dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: you should modify the string to one of the formats supported by c#, then use parse exact method to avoid any problems with format.

Answer (score 2):

As we can see that the input date will be in the format `ddMMyyyy` so here the best option for converting the input to DateTime object is `DateTime.TryParseExact` the code for this will be :

```
string FinancialYear = "01042016-31032017";
string[] splitDate = FinancialYear.Split('-');
DateTime startDate ;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(splitDate[0],"ddMMyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out startDate))
{
    // Proceed with the startDate it will have the required date
}
else
     // Show failure message
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create an Enumerable where index 0 is the first date and index 1 is the second date.

```
string FinancialYear = "01042016-31032017";
var dateRange = FinancialYear.Split('-')
    .Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure of the format your best bet is using [DateTime.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [DateTime.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

You are not 100% guaranteed that the date will be parsed correctly, especially in cases where the day and month numbers could be in the wrong order.

It is best to specify a required date format if you can so you can be sure the date was parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if you string is in static format, you can convert it by reconvert it to valid string format first such as

```
string validstring = splitDate[0].ToString().Substring(4,4)+"-"+splitDate[0].ToString().Substring(2,2) +"-"+ splitDate[0].ToString().Substring(0,2);
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(validstring,"dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: you should apply @un-lucky answer, it will handle everything you need